# 2 sample t test using apply function in R

Tags: r, apply, simulation

I want to know whether it is possible to do the two sample t test using R for simulated data using `apply` function. I know this can do using a for loop. But i am trying to do using apply function.

Here is what is got so far,

```
set.seed(26581) 

data.simu1 = replicate(n=2, rnorm(20,mean=10,sd=2))
data.simu2 = replicate(n=2, rnorm(10,mean=10,sd=2))

apply(data.simu1, 2, function(data.simu1) 
      t.test(data.simu1, data.simu2, var.equal = T)$p.value)
```

Although this does not give any error, I know this is wrong because the answer that I got from the below code is different from what I got above.

```
t.test(data.simu2[,1],data.simu1[,1],alternative="two.sided",var.equal = T)$p.value

t.test(data.simu2[,2],data.simu1[,2],alternative="two.sided",var.equal = T)$p.value
```

Can any one help me to figure out the difference?

Comment: Your problem is that you're not comparing col1 vs. col2 of `data.sim1` and `data.sim2`, but you're comparing col1 of `data.sim1` vs. col1 of `data.sim2` and the same for col2. So, you need to let your process know which columns you're using each time.

Comment: What is your desired result? The below or above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `apply` call is pairing each column of *data.simu1* to **all** columns of *data.simu2* or the entire matrix. See the equivalent non-looped, long form below:

```
apply(data.simu1, 2, function(data.simu1) 
  t.test(data.simu1, data.simu2, var.equal = T)$p.value)
# [1] 0.2521314 0.1958193

t.test(data.simu1[,1], data.simu2, var.equal = T)$p.value
# [1] 0.2521314

t.test(data.simu1[,2], data.simu2, var.equal = T)$p.value
# [1] 0.1958193
```

Since you need to pair each column of the matrices elementwise, use `mapply`, the **m**ultiple variable **apply** function iterating through columns:

```
mapply(function(i, j) 
  t.test(data.simu1[,i], data.simu2[,j], var.equal = T)$p.value, 
  1:ncol(data.simu1), 1:ncol(data.simu2))
# [1] 0.5674294 0.5132492
```

Equivalent to the long form as you posted:

```
t.test(data.simu2[,1],data.simu1[,1],alternative="two.sided",var.equal = T)$p.value
# [1] 0.5674294

t.test(data.simu2[,2],data.simu1[,2],alternative="two.sided",var.equal = T)$p.value
# [1] 0.5132492
```

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help.